# Asp.Net GridView Click Row Redirect to URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an ASP.Net data bound GridView, which I want on clicking a row to open a URL passing the ID of selected row. The ID is a column in the database table, howewver I don't want to show it to the user.

If I set the ID column visibility to false, it doesn't populate the column with the data. i.e. `e.Row.Cells[0].Text` returns an empty string.

The below code is working, but I want to to work with ID column not showing.

In .aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView 
                id="GridViewTest"
                runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="sqlSource" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowDataBound="GridViewTest_RowDataBound"
                >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Name" />
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

In .cs file:

```
protected void GridViewTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = $"location.href = 'default.aspx?appID={e.Row.Cells[0].Text}'";
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use itemtemplate?If you don't want ID to show,  you can add a style attribute display:none

Comment: Updated my answer (again).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're selecting the right cell. For ex, if I have Select and Edit buttons showing, I have to get the 3rd cell:

```
txtbox.Text = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
```

Or, you need to convert the ID field to a template field, which creates a control you can find.

```
// get the label inside the ItemTemplate.
Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("Label1");

// get the label's text and put it into a textbox.
txtbox.Text = lbl.Text;
```

Comment: It's definintely the right cell. Cells[0] is blank, and Cells[1] has the content of next item. Cells[0] works if the field is visible. If the field visible is set to false it's just empty.

Comment: Did you make it a template field? In design view, gridview tasks > edit columns > select the column on the left > convert this field to template (link on the right).

Comment: A template field has the same issue, if I hid it with css, although I worked out how to do it now, posted answer. Although unsure if this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I set DataKeyNames property to the name of datbase table column I wanted to use, in this case ID.

```
    <asp:GridView 
                    id="GridViewTest"
                    runat="server" 
                    DataSourceID="sqlSource" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                     OnRowDataBound="GridViewAppInstallCount_RowDataBound"
                    DataKeyNames="ID"
                    >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DisplayName" HeaderText="Name" />
</Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

The used this code to retrieve the value:

```
protected void GridViewTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = $"location.href = 'default.aspx?appID={GridViewTest.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["ID"]}'";
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
    }
```